# Problem with Wifi in Asus Rog Strix G15 2021

Tags: fedora, wifi, asus

I am facing this problem: When i connect to my wifi it works ok for a moment and then i go to fast.com to check my speed connection and then wifi stops working.

I have an Asus Rog Strix G15 2021 Model: G513QM

OS: Fedora 37 Workstation 64 bits. I runned this command to see my wifi driver info:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
```

Output:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7961]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:4680]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
```

Then i run `modinfo mt7921e` and outputs:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/6.3.3-202.rog.fc37.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt7921/mt7921e.ko.xz
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
author:         Lorenzo Bianconi <lorenzo@kernel.org>
author:         Sean Wang <sean.wang@mediatek.com>
firmware:       mediatek/WIFI_MT7922_patch_mcu_1_1_hdr.bin
firmware:       mediatek/WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1.bin
firmware:       mediatek/WIFI_MT7961_patch_mcu_1_2_hdr.bin
firmware:       mediatek/WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7961_1.bin
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000616sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000608sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007922sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007961sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mt7921-common,mt76-connac-lib,mt76
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mt7921e
vermagic:       6.3.3-202.rog.fc37.x86_64 SMP preempt mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Fedora kernel signing key
sig_key:        01:A6:66:94:7B:CA:9D:D2:A5:3E:D2:66:F9:C1:23:45:B8:3C:BA:92
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
signature:      38:82:98:BF:43:B1:83:AD:49:DC:B5:7C:85:BB:8D:29:ED:3C:E0:89:
        6A:51:CA:2E:89:8F:9B:E4:07:2F:A9:2F:D6:2A:CE:25:50:B6:83:46:
        30:33:6C:B3:8D:5D:C0:5A:36:10:14:51:D7:8E:A3:83:8F:09:1A:E0:
        97:B6:FE:87:DD:83:1A:7B:5C:51:6D:09:C8:CF:9C:83:7D:FD:F4:DB:
        2F:E1:F3:2F:02:B5:CB:29:57:4E:D7:62:E3:C0:EB:8C:56:16:08:86:
        81:A0:FE:04:9E:3E:87:A7:E7:9F:76:87:A1:E2:7C:50:12:73:01:8F:
        35:4A:D9:30:54:B4:DC:5A:07:E7:63:EB:44:2E:94:83:A9:A4:73:6A:
        E3:8C:12:7D:47:0E:9E:A8:BF:9A:D7:13:51:1A:66:E9:D1:92:B7:20:
        E2:AF:92:D1:99:24:EA:84:F3:63:68:4F:12:2B:04:FE:98:7B:DA:3B:
        57:C5:F3:66:08:BF:77:C8:90:6F:72:E5:CC:6E:A6:8C:D8:14:4B:7A:
        10:23:82:FC:3C:8C:38:FF:EA:E6:C7:FB:D9:7A:C6:11:38:B7:C1:43:
        C4:54:9E:F2:FC:96:3F:3C:C2:3E:8B:F5:BB:9D:C0:19:CC:3C:8F:DA:
        95:C4:04:87:6C:95:86:06:9F:61:20:6A:B3:38:30:66:15:03:68:54:
        31:F4:BA:03:DD:5B:A1:BF:16:8E:2F:14:77:53:CE:EB:16:A3:95:55:
        AC:36:7A:81:2A:F6:5A:30:53:0A:43:8E:7E:9C:59:C4:6E:8C:4E:F1:
        41:48:CB:33:60:11:06:97:5D:59:B2:11:14:9C:AA:61:43:BE:2A:39:
        04:4B:28:BC:80:F1:A5:10:46:FA:63:BC:CF:7C:A4:9E:D6:16:2D:D2:
        B6:27:7C:5D:C0:1A:2A:B2:9C:30:89:84:B8:C8:87:89:02:56:B6:23:
        B2:A5:39:08:4C:12:9C:AB:0E:BD:23:32:8F:BF:80:8F:8C:85:BF:9F:
        FA:9C:7B:6D:E1:32:AC:15:80:EA:5D:36:5D:AE:F3:73:55:BF:4A:44:
        96:78:18:D5:9A:AF:BA:B7:4E:74:A6:3F:F8:D0:D1:96:24:BA:28:C3:
        AA:FE:41:1F:B3:0E:C2:BB:79:9A:B8:E0:A9:99:2A:87:08:92:6E:29:
        B1:8A:22:06:D3:5F:29:7E:65:A7:BF:A4:CA:3B:04:2E:4F:48:7E:31:
        DD:F1:0F:31:2E:22:9A:19:18:04:39:0C:19:7A:4F:C2:3F:4F:A4:C4:
        C7:FA:9A:33:A2:08:CB:24:A0:74:25:39:43:DF:83:DF:94:DF:D5:05:
        68:A6:23:3B:47:AF:D6:CC:DA:1E:4F:5B
parm:           disable_aspm:disable PCI ASPM support (bool)
```

I have another router acting as a repeater for my parents room and when i connect to that network it works ok and fast.com works also.

I have no clue but im thinking on installing Fedora 38 to see if it solves the problem but i use this system for work so it will be slow to backup everything and reinstalling again the OS. Any help?